# Crawl file server to add files to search result

Tags: search-results, file, sharepoint-server, crawl-external-content

I'm trying to add some directories from my file server to be included in the Search Center in SharePoint 2013. I have added a new content source to be crawled and stated it is a file server. I filled in the path `\\fileserver\test`
After doing a full crawl i get this error :

> Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access
>   Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl
>   this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint
>   repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read"
>   permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled.

I don't have any clue how to fix this error, i'm very new to SharePoint.

Thanks !

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the default content access account to my user account. Everything works fine now !

Comment: So PirateEric's answer is the correct one, and not this one. Right?

Comment: No it's not... I can't add the NT Authority\network service to the folder if you noticed that in my posts...... i CHANGED the default content access account to my account not what he suggested...

Comment: Well that just seems like a hack for not having configured a correct default access account to me

Comment: didn't configure anything... was the default option...

Comment: Using your personal login as the default access acount is not really best practice.

Comment: I don't know i'm pretty new to SP myself so... Is there a better option?

Comment: Check this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ijasari/archive/2011/04/15/sharepoint-2010-search-service-application-crawl-configuration-for-anonymous-sharepoint-site.aspx but skip the two "Enable.." headings since they are for anonymous access sites (I know it's 2010, but it is kind of the same story in 2013)

Comment: This gives the user full read control on the SP site but not on the file share?

Comment: Yepp, the file server is another piece and you add control to that as you always do..

Answer (score 4):

The user account that operates the search crawling has to be given read permission to the file share you wish to crawl.

Comment: How do I find which account this is?

Comment: In central admin, manage service applications, Search Service. It will be the Default content access account.

Comment: my default content acces account is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE but how do I give this account full read permissions?

Comment: can I change this account to my account without any trouble?

Comment: A dedicated user account is preferred. What happens if you leave the company? Now search is hosed because it's running as you.

Comment: I will try to add an account to the AD named SPSearch and set that account as the default content access account so there won't be any trouble in the future.